# In TypeScript is there any "annotation" for methods to indicate a variable won't be null after exiting it?

Tags: typescript, annotations, undefined

In TypeScript with `strict: true` config, consider the following scenario:

```
export class A {

    a?: string;
    b?: number;

    init() {
        this.a = "";
        this.b = 0;
    }

    opA() {
        this.requireInit();
        const something = this.a.length; // Error here
    }

    opB() {
        this.requireInit();
        const something = this.b.toString(); // Error here
    }

    private requireInit() {
        if (this.a === undefined || this.b === undefined) {
            throw new Error("Call init before using this method");
        }
    }

}
```

Is there a way to mark `requireInit` method that after calling that method, `a` and `b` members is not undefined anymore so I do not have to use `!` in every method? In C# there is a similar Attribute called [`MemberNotNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#helper-methods-membernotnull-and-membernotnullwhen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making `requireInit` into an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) that asserts that its `this` definitely has those properties will do the trick.

```
class A {

    a?: string;
    b?: number;

    init() {
        this.a = "";
        this.b = 0;
    }

    opA() {
        this.requireInit();
        const something = this.a.length; // OK now
    }

    opB() {
        this.requireInit();
        const something = this.b.toString(); // OK now
    }

    private requireInit(): asserts this is { a: string, b: number } {
        if (this.a === undefined || this.b === undefined) {
            throw new Error("Call init before using this method");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great! One small catch I wonder if there is a workaround: after that, I cannot assign `a` back to `undefined` anymore (for example, a `cleanUp` function that requires `init` but after that it would set `a` to `undefined`). I have to set it to `this.a = undefined as any`. Is there any better way or that is the "de-factor" way?

Comment: You could change the cleanup function to an assertion function as well, that transforms it back into `{ a?: string, b?: number }`. Personally, I avoid these sorts of issues by not mutating objects - creating new ones of the proper absolute type to begin with usually makes things easier.